# Output data by date range

Tags: php, mysql, loops, date, output

i want to output the rate by dates

Eg: if the user picks a date "2015-08-23 to 2015-08-25" the output of the rates should be 400 + 599 = 999

Right now my query only gets the last date so it only output 1 rate of that date

EG: i select 2015-08-23 to 2015-08-25 so the total rate should be 999, but it outputs 599 instead

sorry if i'm not clear enough

```
id rid rate sdate               edate
 1   1  400 2015-08-22 00:00:00 2015-08-22 00:00:00
 2   1  400 2015-08-23 00:00:00 2015-08-23 00:00:00
 3   1  599 2015-08-24 00:00:00 2015-08-24 00:00:00
 4   1  599 2015-08-25 00:00:00 2015-08-25 00:00:00
 5   1  599 2015-08-26 00:00:00 2015-08-26 00:00:00
 6   1  599 2015-08-27 00:00:00 2015-08-27 00:00:00
 7   1  599 2015-08-28 00:00:00 2015-08-28 00:00:00
 8   1  599 2015-08-29 00:00:00 2015-08-29 00:00:00
 9   1  599 2015-08-30 00:00:00 2015-08-30 00:00:00
10   1  599 2015-08-31 00:00:00 2015-08-31 00:00:00
```

PHP

```
$dateentry = array();
    // populate $dateentry array with dates
    while (strtotime($ci) <= strtotime($co)) {
          $dateentry[] =  date("Y-m-d", strtotime($ci));
          $ci = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($ci)));
    } // end while
    foreach($dateentry as $spd){
       echo $spd.'<br/>';
       $rating =$dbo->prepare('SELECT rid,sdate,edate,rate FROM rates WHERE rid='.$row->id.' AND (sdate=? AND edate=?) ');
       if(!$rating->execute(array($spd,$check_out))){
           print_r($rating->errorInfo());
       }
           $rates12 = $rating->fetch();
           $rate .= $rates12["rate"];
       }
```

Comment: Your rate looks oddly like a string, and it's odd that a range should start and end at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need to sum only the rates that are different between dates then you can change your query like this.

```
$dbo->prepare(
    'SELECT sum(a.rate) FROM (
        SELECT rate from rates 
            WHERE 1=1
                AND rid='.$row->id.'
                AND (sdate>=? AND edate<=?)
            group by rate
    ) as a'
);
```

Probably there might be a solution to do it in one query too.

if you need to sum all the rates then you can simply use the following query

```
$dbo->prepare(
    'SELECT sum(rate) FROM rates
        WHERE 1=1
            AND rid='.$row->id.'
            AND (sdate>=? AND edate<=?)'
);
```

Comment: i select 2015-08-26 to 2015-08-28 the output is 2396;
my database:
26 the rate is 250 & 27 is 599, the should total 849

Comment: I can't see the problem http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/56814/1/0 can you give me more details please check the link.

Comment: okay, so it's nothing wrong with the query, it's probably my output, bcoz i output the room details which is in another table call "rooms" then i loop it after that i write another query in the (room) loop to output the rates, then i loop the rates.

Comment: rite now i tried using your code but it outputs nothing, there's no errors. its blank like this (nett)

Comment: The query above is just an example. Have you tried modifying this example according to your needs? For example if you are using this query somewhere else you might need to alias the ``sum(rate)``. Also have you tried executing only this query directly to you database without all the other things you are mentioning above? Does it return any result? Final if I understood correctly what rate is then the schema is against normalization http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php

Answer (score 0):

So you want to get all the rows where

```
(sdate >= '2015-08-23' AND edate <= '2015-08-25')
```

So change the query to

```
"SELECT rid,sdate,edate,rate 
   FROM rates 
  WHERE rid=$row->id
    AND (sdate >= ? AND edate <= ?)";
```